# Python Wand is growing file sizes

Tags: python-2.7, wand

I am trying to use python Wand library but any manipulation I do ends with resulting files being much larger (file size) than the original! Consider the following simple example I am testing on my Ubuntu machine:

```
with Image(filename='input.pdf', resolution=300) as test:
    test.save(filename='output.pdf')
```

My input file is a scanned document of 10 pages at resolution 300dpi. It takes 3mb on disk. If I don't specify the resolution when opening the image, the output pdf is only 1mb but is in a very poor quality (unreadable). When specifying the resolution 300 (same as original), the resulting file is 30mb, 10x larger thant the original !

Any help on how to simply being able to save an image with the same compression/resolution as the original would be appreciated.

Thanks!